# MariaDB 10.1 and Ubuntu 16.04: Unable to set password for the MariaDB "root" user

Tags: server, 16.04, mysql, mariadb

When trying to install MariaDB 10.1 in an Ubuntu 16.04 Server with previous MySQL installed, even purging MySQL with `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`, I get this error message and the install process fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that everything is clean, you not only need to purge MySQL (and MariaDB) with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*
```

But you also need to remove old MySQL config folders, with:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql-files
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql-keyring
```

After these steps and [correctly adding the MariaDB repositories](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/), you can finally:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

Comment: One liner to remove config folders: `sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql && sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql-files && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql-keyring`